# ISAPI filter crashes IIS

Tags: iis, filter, isapi, crash

I have created an ISAPI filter.
It works fine on develpoment server and SIT server.

But in production server it doesn't works.

In event viewer the following log :

Reporting queued error: faulting application w3wp.exe, version 6.0.3790.2825, faulting module msvcr80.dll, version 8.0.50727.3053, fault address 0x00046039.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there isn't really sufficient information here to tell what is going on. What you really need to understand is what conditions are causing the problem. The good old [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) are your friend here. If you aern't familliar with using the debugger then tools like [ADPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) and [Debug Diag](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en) will be useful to you.  You also might want to check out [Tess Ferrandez's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) which is an excellent resource if you are looking for advice debugging within IIS.

An off the cuff guess might be that something is passing an invalid pointer to one of the C-runtime functions. Using the debugger you should be able to identify what that function is and what the arguments being passed are. Hopefully armed with that information you will be able to figure out what is going on.

Comment: The same dll(ISAPI filter) works fine in development enviroment(winxp) and SIT environment(windows server 2003) but not in production environment(windows server 2003).

Moreover we will not able to install anything in production server)

Is there any other way to resolve this issue

Comment: You could try using Application Verifier in your development environment to see if this will provoke your application to fail under controlled conditions (try enabling Page Heap). 

Failing that you might be able to pursuade the owner of the production system to let you put the debugging tools on. You don't have to install the package to get them on there. A file copy will do and you can delete it afterwards. This argument has worked for me.

Comment: Tess rocks!...also David Wang's old articles are gems as well. Sadly he no longer blogs :(

Answer (score 1):

When faced with this problem, I grabbed [Jochen Klambach's StackWalker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx) from CodeProject.  **Update:** [StackWalker has now graduated to Codeplex](http://stackwalker.codeplex.com/).  Definitely get the codeplex release; it includes several updates and fixes.

It will print the stack for your code when the filter crashes.

The way I did it was this: within OnAuthComplete in my filter, which is where my filter does all the work, I surrounded the logic with a try...except:

```
__try
{
    dwRetval = DoRewrites(...);
}
__except ( ExcFilter(GetExceptionInformation()) )
{
}
```

And then, ExcFilter is defined this way:

```
extern "C" int ExcFilter(EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pExp)
{
    MyLoggingStackWalker *sw = new MyLoggingStackWalker();
    sw->ShowCallstack(GetCurrentThread(), pExp->ContextRecord);
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;  // allow the process to crash
}
```

The LoggingStackWalker derives from StackWalker, and overrides the OnOutput method to send that output to a log file.  It also sets the search path for PDB files to include the directory where the DLL is found.

```
class MyLoggingStackWalker : public StackWalker
{
public:
    MyLoggingStackWalker() : StackWalker()
        {
            char drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
            char dir[_MAX_DIR];

            // add the directory for the ISAPI DLL, to the search path for PDB files
            this->m_szSymPath = (LPSTR) malloc(_MAX_PATH);
            _splitpath_s(DllLocation, drive, _MAX_DRIVE, dir, _MAX_DIR, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
            _makepath_s(this->m_szSymPath, _MAX_PATH, drive, dir, NULL, NULL);
        }
    virtual void OnOutput(LPCSTR szText)
        {
            LogMessage((char*)szText);
            StackWalker::OnOutput(szText);
        }
};
```

To demonstrate it, I pass a bad pointer into vscprintf in the code. This is what the resulting stack trace looks like on IIS7.  You can see the first couple frames are in the C runtime, with line numbers, too.  (The StackWalker actually downloads symbol files from the MS symbol server, if you use the default settings.  You can turn this off if you like.)
Then the next bunch of frames are from my code.  It pinpoints the location of the problem.  The stack frames following mine - Those are all the IIS modules.  This is IIS7 on Vista; I guess the symbol server didn't have symbols for those modules. Anyway as you can see the stacktrace leaves no doubt as to where the problem is.

```
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\output.c (1068): _output_l
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\vsprintf.c (405): _vscprintf_helper
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\vsprintf.c (414): _vscprintf
c:\dev\isapi\filter\logger.c (193): LogMessage
c:\dev\isapi\filter\rewriter.c (2036): EvaluateRewrites
c:\dev\isapi\filter\rewriter.c (789): DoRewrites
c:\dev\isapi\filter\rewriter.c (955): OnAuthComplete
c:\dev\isapi\filter\rewriter.c (1139): HttpFilterProc
60531896 module(filter): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
60531FAB module(filter): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
605314E3 module(filter): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
60531276 module(filter): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
6D122EA0 module(iiscore): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
6D123696 module(iiscore): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
6D12AA4C module(iiscore): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
6D125D3B module(iiscore): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
6D1220F4 module(iiscore): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
6D124EEF module(iiscore): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
6D12C6B8 module(iiscore): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
70CB13B3 module(w3dt): (filename not available): UlAtqGetContextProperty
70CB11DA module(w3dt): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
71A42611 module(W3TP): (filename not available): THREAD_POOL::PostCompletion
71A42812 module(W3TP): (filename not available): OverrideThreadPoolConfigWithRegistry
71A41E85 module(W3TP): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
76A54911 module(kernel32): (filename not available): BaseThreadInitThunk
7727E4B6 module(ntdll): (filename not available): __RtlUserThreadStart
7727E489 module(ntdll): (filename not available): _RtlUserThreadStart
7727E489 module(ntdll): (filename not available): _RtlUserThreadStart
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to attach to the process and debug it using visual studio.  You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to figure out which w3wp.exe process is running your dll and the Remote Debugging Tool to allow you to debug code on another machine.